# Filter an array of objects by an array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angular.js

This code is the whole logic for the [AngularJS ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) lib. I'm not (yet) a JS pro and still learning AngularJS as well but I'm pretty sure this can be done a little more efficient? I'm talking especially about the `search:` part of the object. In php I would probably do something like array_diff. Any critiques are welcome!

The reason for the `selectedIds: []` is that I use ng-repeat to render a list of hidden fields with `name="users[]"` to be able to fetch the list as a php array on the server side. I'm not suing Angular as a single page app here, I'm just using it for all the widgets but the data itself is submitted with the whole page as POST.

The `for (var key in result.data)` is done to filter already selected ids out of the array. It was the most easy solution to avoid the error `Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed.`. Sure I could pass the already existing ids to the lookup GET request but I think this works fine on the client side as well.

```
$scope.usersList = {
    items: [],
    selected: [],
    selectedIds: [],
    extractIds: function() {
        $scope.usersList.selectedIds = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.usersList.selected.length; i++) {
            $scope.usersList.selectedIds.push($scope.usersList.selected[i].id);
        }
    },
    select: function($item, $model) {
        this.extractIds();
    },
    remove: function($item, $model) {
        this.extractIds();
    },
    search: function(term) {
        if (term.length > 2) {
            UsersService.lookup(term).then(function(result) {
                for (var key in result.data) {
                    if (result.data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        if ($scope.usersList.selectedIds.indexOf(result.data[key].id) != -1) {
                            delete result.data[key];
                        };
                    }
                }
                $scope.usersList.items = result.data;
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: FYI "Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed." can be avoided by `track by $index`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

welcome to CodeReview :-)

Firstly, I would mention that your `$item` and `$model` parameters should just be `item` and `model`. The dollar-sign prefix is conventionally reserved for official vendor libraries from Angular, and should not be used in your code to prevent confusion. I initially thought `$model` was a derivative of ngModel!

Secondly, do you **need** selectedIds? Can you not just use a function to extract those IDs? You do not need to watch a seperate array of IDs.

<strike>Thirdly - `delete result.data[key]` - this is not how you use delete. You use delete to remove properties from objects, not key/value pairs from collections. Instead, you should just set it to undefined.. with that said, you don't even need to use `delete` here anyway.</strike>

Fourthly.. what the hell is going on with `for(key in result.data) if(result.data.hasOwnProperty(key)`... that code is iterating the data then checking that the data has that property. wat. This works for circumventing prototypal inheritance, however you can just as easily use `Object.keys()`. Not to mention that the result of a `$http` request is only going to inherit from `Object`.

With that said, here's a refactor of your code. You will need lodash for this code to work, but no worries - lodash is probably the most handy library you will ever come across in JS. I use it on every project these days.

```
$scope.usersList = {
  items: [],
  search: function(term) {
    if(term.length > 2) {
      UsersService.lookup(term)
        .then(function(xhr) {
          return _.reject(xhr.data, function(item) {
            return _.contains($scope.usersList.items, item);
          });
        })
        .then(function(data) {
          $scope.usersList.items = data;
        });
    }
  }
};
```

I've removed the `select`, `remove` and `extractId` functions as they do nothing in my example (and they did nothing anyway!)

This could definitely be refactored even better in my opinion, but I would need more scope on the actual problem to do that. For example, there's no need to use the `$scope` here aside from exposing the results to the view. This would be much better done if it was encapsulated inside of a function and only the result was exposed. This should **really** be in two separate classes at least.

Comment: `delete result.data[key]` is how you use delete. It is removing the property given by `key` from the `data` object. Also, the bit you are talking about in your 'fourthly' filters inherited properties (e.g. if someone has messed with the `Object` prototype).

Comment: My mistake on the delete part, then. It looked like an array >.> As for the inherited properties bit, yeah, I know what it does, but it does not make sense here. The `results.data` will only inherit from `Object`. You can simply use something like I have suggested to circumvent accessing the prototype. I see no reason as to why you would iterate the object in this way. For example, `Object.keys` [ignores the prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Comment: Completely agree that it's not necessary. I think `Object.keys` is IE9+ whereas angular mostly works on IE8 so might not be an option but as you've already shown, don't need to iterate at all.

Comment: That's true but there are polyfills for IE8 for `Object.keys` available. I think if this was a legitimate concern the code author would have sought out a polyfill.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm already using loadash 2.4.1. I've tried your changed code, and I think I understand it mostly but for some reason it doesn't work. I'm getting the items I've filtered before in my for / if part of the code again in the list. And what exactly is `_`? I haven't noticed this before in any other code think.

Comment: `_` is lodash. "I'm getting the items I've filtered before in my for / if part of the code again in the list" - I didn't set the array to anything, so that might be why. But otherwise I'm not sure. I didn't test the code, but if it still doesn't work after I make this amendment I'll see if I can actually make it work for you

Comment: Thank you, well, I can try to make it work myself :) I don't want others to do my work, I'm just trying to see if there is a better solution because I wasn't happy myself with the for / if part of the code. The whole key is to filter the records out I already have in the array. See my updated answer. I'm going to read lodashs documentation now. ;)

Comment: @Dan The hasOwnProperty thing is a JSHINT suggestion I think...
Since you already use lodash,  I would recommend trying a custom build that best suits your needs...

Comment: @malix We've already gone over the hasownproperty thing - I'm not sure why you are pointing out custom builds :s

Comment: Sorry @DanPantry, did not mean to offend...

Nobody had mentionned jshint, and you said "what the hell is going on with for(key in result.data) if(result.data.hasOwnProperty(key)"

I was trying to explain that maybe the OP had gotten a refactoring suggestion from webstorm/jshint/etc to add an hasOwnProperty check to mitigate a possible "error"...

Also, I was suggesting a custom build if the OP was going to add lodash and only make limited use of it:

"Custom builds make it easy to create lightweight versions of lodash containing only the features you need"
 -- https://lodash.com/custom-builds

Comment: @malix no offense taken, friend. I never noticed the Jshint suggestion for time around. I understand what custom builds are useful for, but I don't really think it was in scope. Nonetheless it's a valid suggestion

Comment: @Dan Pantry I would flag this as correct but your code that replaces my nested if / for part doesn't work for me. Everything else is fine.

Comment: try

    return $scope.usersList.selectedIds.indexOf(item.id) == -1;

instead of

    return _.contains($scope.usersList.items, item);

?